# Is there a way to export rendered image/svg+xml?

Tags: xml, svg

I am working on a template engine that generates image/svg+xml for site graphics.

Is there a way to export this that would export/save them as a file?

PNG would be preferable, because of transparency.

Something even better would capture the HTML and CSS for offline view.

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: I am platform independent. I have a Linux, OSX and Windows box I work from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) has tools to rasterize SVG and export the result as PNG (among other formats).

Comment: So, I would need to write a scrip that works with this to parse pages I feed it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use webkit's renderer instead of apache's, here's a phantomjs hack I made that takes an svg and saves it as a png: https://gist.github.com/2946954

Comment: Feel free to upgrade it to the sanctioned answer, if you find it handier than Batik (I certainly do, but I am biased :-).